# Concatenate cells but exclude 'empties' in Excel/Google Sheets with line breaks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to figure out how to concentrate data in list form(line breaks) that would exclude blank cells (when not filled in our when filled in auto populate). I received the below formula, however this text wrapping method wont work for what I am doing. I need to be able to copy and paste the results into emails and the below produces a long sting of data with out line breaks.Is there a method to insert line breaks and have 'blank' cell not populate and auto populate when data is entered?

FIY, current data A1:I1 (listed in column)

=IF(A1="","",A1&"          ")&IF(B1="","",B1&"          ")&IF(C1="","",C1&"          ")&IF(D1="","",D1&"          ")&IF(E1="","",E1&"          ")&IF(F1="","",F1&"          ")&IF(G1="","",G1&"          ")&IF(H1="","",H1&"          ")&IF(I1="","",I1&"          ")

Thanks for any insight that you may be able to offer, been trying to find a solution for a couple of days with little success.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try *(Excel)*:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:A11)
```

[image]

`CHAR(10)` is the "give me a break" character.

**EDIT#1:**

To go across, use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:I1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so what I am really trying to do is the above with A1:A11, but also trying to get is additional columns (all text data with spaces) such as, A1 A2 A3 (line break) B1 B2 B3 (line break)  C1 C2 C3 (line Break) and so on.... I can get them to line break and show in a single cell, but can't manage to remove the blanks between non blanks and have it adjust to non blanks only(excluding all blanks)....any ideas?

Comment: SEE CORRECTION!!!  Thanks for the quick response, so what I am really trying to do is the above with A1:A11, but also trying to get is additional columns (all text data with spaces) such as, A1 B1 C1 (line break) A2 B2 C2 (line break)  A3 B3 C3 (line Break) and so on.... I can get them to line break and show in a single cell, but can't manage to remove the blanks between non blanks and have it adjust to non blanks only(excluding all blanks)....any ideas?

Comment: @Capt.Drew  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: So, if I just say "CHAR(10)", do you think they'll know what I mean?  :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch  Yes.  If you want to insert a hard-return in a cell **by formula**, then use something like `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1`  If you want to insert a hard-return **while typing**, use ALT-ENTER.

Comment: No, I meant the translation to "Give me a break".  Sorry, duh, no more lame attempts at humor.

Comment: @Bandersnatch  my sense of humor is pretty bad.  I tell people that if I could afford better writers, I would tell better jokes.